# How to explain and troubleshoot fan running at full speed, but CPU use at 15%?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, fan, temperature

Using W7, up to date on a Lenovo W510. No virtualization.
No "toolbars", no "help improve user experience" software that I know.

From time to time I've this situation:

- Fan full speed, air very hot.
- Satisfying responsiveness of Windows.
- Resource monitor shows a high CPU frequency, e.g. 107% (usual range is 5% to 60% with my UEFI settings, unless I run some heavy load task, but in this case I'm not surprised)
- CPU overall utilization low, can be 15% - 30%.
- No significant increase of CPU utilization curves on any of the cores.

At this time I may have usual applications running, including Firefox (up to date, currently 49) with some well known addons, Adobe Reader (up to date).

Sometimes memory use by Firefox is constantly increasing, restarting Firefox is sufficient to stop this, sometimes rebooting is necessary. Sometimes while rebooting I find out that an update of Adobe Reader was waiting for the reboot to be installed.

My questions:

- **About CPU use being displayed as *low***: How can the temperature / fan speed increase so much with only 15% CPU use according to the resource monitor? Isn't the tool supposed to capture all activity in Windows? Could that be other chips (e.g. GPU) causing the temperature increase?
- **About discrepancy between CPU utilization and frequency**: Why would the CPU frequency increase to the max (107%) if the CPU is not really used?
- **About the ways to troubleshoot this problem**: If the resource monitor is not helpful, what can I do to try to find the cause?

Comment: Process Explorer can tell you what the GPU is doing. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: Are you simply bothered by the fact the fan always runs?

Comment: @Ramhound: This happens not so frequently and I'm grateful to the fan to protect the chips. I'm more bothered by what is overloading the system and is not reported on Resource Monitor.

Comment: "Why would the CPU frequency increase to the max (107%) if the CPU is not really used?" - Your CPU has the capability to boost its frequency based on it's current temperature.  This is a good thing...

Comment: just looking at title.. if fan runs high even when cpu use is low then maybe cpu is running hot. So you could check the heatsink eg try a new one or reapply it with paste.

Comment: @Ramhound: Reference? My last reading on this matter was that the CPU clock would be slowed down when the junction temperature goes high.

Comment: "Air is very hot" isn't very descriptive but your frequency being 108% indicates your CPUs frequency is boosted

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU**, **Power Usage** and click to start. Captue 1 minute of the low CPU usage and high CPU clock, now click on **Save** to save the data into a ETL file. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Not yet. What should I look in this trace ? (I'm probably not going to put system data online for obvious security reasons)

Comment: forget it, you won't see anything in it. put it into my dropbox, so only I can look at the file: https://www.dropbox.com/request/R7lCcOTI2Y7OHTqoiTqg